# Need open source simple 3D software renderer

Tags: c#, 3d

Is there any good open source software renderer for C#?

I need a small and simple library for rendering simple 3D objects, Not DirectX or XNA.

Comment: because they need to be installed and they are not open source.

Comment: OpenGL isn't really open source either, so I don't think (on Windows, at least) you'll find a fully open source hardware renderer. Typically, however, that's not an issue, and plenty of open source software uses one or the other. It depends on your intent/requirements.

Comment: Did you find one? How simple do you need it?

Answer (score -1):

Try [Axiom](http://axiom3d.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is a C# port of Ogre 3D. I have not worked with Axiom myself, but with Ogre 3D and its a robust 3D library with a good community. Alternatively check out the [game engine list on GPWiki](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines) and see if you find anything that suits your needs.

Comment: Axiom is not a software renderer, it uses DX or OpenGL (SlimDX and other C# wrappers) underneath.

Comment: XNA is not a software renderer per sé either but a programming framework which, among other things, supports 3D rendering - a similarity it shares with Axiom. IMHO the OP's main intend was to find some libraries he can use to render 3D objects without being restricted by some kind of license.

Comment: The question _specifically states_ not XNA (so Axiom's similarity further rules it out) and asks for a **software** renderer. This is not an answer to the current question (why the OP needs a software renderer, I don't know, but for now, that's what it says).

Comment: It is not the similarity that plays a role but what *distinguishes* both, namely Axiom being Open Source. But as, as you state, we do not exactly know what the OP actually needs the libraries for, and as long as that is the case any discussion is just an exchange of opinions.